# 'File name too long' error when building Spring with Gradle

Tags: spring, gradle

I tried to build Spring from source using: `./gradlew install`

It fails with:

```
/home/dk/.gradle/caches/1.12/scripts/build_68eiq5ktt9740a7l1bofab8a9a/ProjectScript/no_buildscript/classes/build_68eiq5ktt9740a7l1bofab8a9a$_run_closure27_closure138_closure139_closure140_closure141_closure142_closure143_closure144_closure146_closure147.class (File name too long)
```

This was [reported earlier](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/social/92765-problem-building-spring-social-with-gradle) but should have been fixed in Gradle 0.9.1. However I still have this error with Gradle 1.12. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 with an ext4 filesystem.

What's the recommend workaround for this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that this error occurs when using an encrypted home directory. I've set `GRADLE_USER_HOME` to an unencrypted directory and everything works fine.

Comment: Worked for me as well

Comment: helped me as well, I createtd symlink with `ln -s /mnt/data/caches/gradle ~/.gradle/caches`

Answer (score 4):

The only solutions I'm aware of are to use a filesystem that can handle long filenames, or to ask the Spring folks to change their build script so that it doesn't use such deep nesting levels (10 seems way too much). In any case, this question should be brought to attention of Spring developers (e.g. in their JIRA). I'd be surprised if none of them used Ubuntu/ext4.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not too late to post it back to this thread. Based on the answer provided by Dennis, Here is what needs to be done to ensure you are able to compile Spring Source on encrypted files system.

```
$ sudo mkdir /opt/gradle/home
$ sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/gradle/home
$ export GRADLE_USER_HOME=/opt/gradle/home # Probably add it to .zshrc or .bashrc files
```